# I want to replace the implementation of a.py Using b.py this way, how to write?

Tags: python-2.7

## a.py

```
class quan(object):
    __couter=0
    def __init__(self):
        cls=self.__class__
        prefix=cls.__name__
        index=cls.__couter
        self.storage_name='_{}#{}'.format(prefix,index)
        cls.__couter+=1

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance,self.storage_name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value>0:
            setattr(instance,self.storage_name,value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('value must be > 0')


class LineItem(object):
    w=quan()
    p=quan()
    def __init__(self,d,w,p):
        self.d=d
        self.w=w
        self.p=p
    def sub(self):
        return self.w * self.p

r=LineItem('aa',10,10)
print r.w,r.p
```

## b.py

```
class quan(object):
    __couter=0
    def __init__(self):
        cls=self.__class__
        prefix=cls.__name__
        index=cls.__couter
        self.storage_name='_{}#{}'.format(prefix,index)
        cls.__couter+=1

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance,self.storage_name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value>0:
            setattr(instance,self.storage_name,value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('value must be > 0')


class LineItem(object):

    def __init__(self,d,w,p):
        self.d=d
        self.w=w
        self.p=p
    def sub(self):
        return self.w * self.p
    @quan
    def w(self,v):
        self._w=v

    @quan
    def p(self,v):
        self._p=v
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please learn [how to format a post](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (espacially how to insert code). Next, please ask a question. A title should summarize your problem, but not state an actual question. Please place some explaining text on where you are strugeling and what you can't get working.

Answer (score 0):

```
#b.py的写法#


class quan(object):

    __couter=0
    def __init__(self,value=0):
        self.value=value
        cls=self.__class__
        prefix=cls.__name__
        index=cls.__couter
        self.storage_name='_{}#{}'.format(prefix,index)
        cls.__couter+=1

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        # return self.value
        return getattr(instance,self.storage_name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # self.value=value+10
        if value>0:
            setattr(instance,self.storage_name,value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('value must be > 0')


class LineItem(object):

    def __init__(self,d,w,p):
        self.d=d
        self.w=w
        self.p=p
    def sub(self):
        return self.w * self.p
    @quan
    def w(self,v):
        self.w=v

    @quan
    def p(self,v):
        self.p=v
r=LineItem('aa',10,10)

print r.w,r.p,r.sub()

print getattr(r,'_quan#0'),getattr(r,'_quan#1')
```